# Redirect from a URL:80 to another URL:xxxxx with Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, url

I would like to be able to type in http://localdnsurl and have it redirect to a more complex url like http://localdnsurl2:12345/web/index.html.

IS there a way to do this Windows Server 2012's DNS service using SRV records?

I've been playing around but so far I've had no success.

I know I could setup another server and run an httpd service which could do a redirect, but I would like to keep the complexity down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTP clients do not know anything about SRV records. You'll need to perform an [HTTP 301 Redirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) using your webserver.